# PDF Form - filling a field in one form reflects in other forms of the same document

Tags: forms, pdf

I am trying to insert many copies of fillable form pdf into another pdf (using Nuance Pdf converter).
These fillable forms should be added before a set of pages in another pdf.

The issue I face is:

> When I fill one form (say in 2nd page), it gets reflected in remaining forms (other pages where the same form is inserted)

The reason should be that all the forms have same field name. Hence, updating a field in one form gets reflected in others also.

Any way to overcome this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to rename the fields, if you want them to keep individual values. Just keep in mind: "one field name, one field value".

It is well possible that Nuance PDF Converter is not able to do this; you might have to look out for a product which does know how to do it.